# somebody help me how make slide with jquery

Tags: jquery, slider

See example http://www.gigya.com/ (on footer)

there a slide using jquery, somebody help me how make that slide

Comment: What have you done so far? Do you just search for free coder?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a

[Easy Slider plugin](http://cssglobe.com/lab/easyslider1.5/02.html)

Usage

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("#slider").easySlider();
});
```

where slider is the id of the container div in which the slides are placed.